# WAS 8.0.0.2: JNDI lookup on persistence-context-ref returns always new EntityManager instance

Tags: jndi, entitymanager, websphere-8

Hi WAS developers,

I have problem that a JNDI lookup on a declared persistence-context-ref always returns a new EntityManager instance. I expect that within one JTA transaction the container provides me always the same EntityManager instance. But multiple EntityManagers within one transaction causes lock trouble! Furthermore the JPA usage is not optimized as entities might be loaded several times (for each EntityManager) within one transaction.

I have to use persistence-context-ref together with JNDI lookups as I have some EJB2.1 in place within a EJB3.1 module. Furthermore I want to have the EntityManager container-managed.

To reproduce just declare a persistence-context-ref on a EJB2.1 SessionBean:

```
<persistence-context-ref>
  <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/MyPersistence</persistence-context-ref-name>
  <persistence-unit-name>MyPersistence</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>
```

Now make twice a JNDI lookup consecutively within an open JTA transaction:

```
context.lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/MyPersistence")
```

You will see that two different EntityManager instances are returned.

Is this a defect in WAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityManager returned from a persistence-context-ref lookup is actually a proxy to a per-transaction EntityManager (a debugger or print will see it is an instance of a JPATxEntityManager), so even though each lookup returns a unique object, they will all interact with the same underlying EntityManager.